# Return a complimenting nucleotide character

Tags: python

What is the best way to return a complementing character of DNA using list comprehension without 4 different `if` statements?

For example:

`A <-> T`
"A" returns "T" and "T" returns "A"

`G <-> C`
"G" returns "C" and "C" returns "G"

Without loops or such. Built-in functions are allowed.

Comment: How about creating a dictionary, that maps A to T etc, and then just looking it up in the dictionary ? It's a more elegant version of if :)

Comment: @Carcigenicate the point is that I've tried 4 if statements and would like to know if anyone has a better way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you have external dictionary like this

```
strand =  'GATTAGAC'

comps = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A' }

comp_strand = [ comps[x] for x in strand ]
```

If you want to tolerate unknown characters in your input, look up 'defaultdict'

Comment: Just a minor syntax error, the opening quotation mark for 'A' is missing the assignment of comps

Answer (score 2):

Another answer from here http://biopython.org/wiki/Seq

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna
>>> my_dna = Seq("AGTACACTGGT", generic_dna)
>>> my_dna
Seq('AGTACACTGGT', DNAAlphabet())
>>> my_dna.complement()
Seq('TCATGTGACCA', DNAAlphabet())
>>> my_dna.reverse_complement()
Seq('ACCAGTGTACT', DNAAlphabet())
```